# In Chrome - CSS transform rotation of parent div causes text to get cut

Tags: css, google-chrome, rotation, transform

I'm building a web page where I have a section that needs to be tilted/rotated 2.5deg (because of the diagonal background), so I've put another container in it with an opposite rotation -2.5deg in order to keep the content horizontal. The problem is when I've scrolled to that section and I refresh the page. Chrome automatically scrolls you to the last place you were on the page and I see text being cut. If i try to select it or if I move around the page (the text getting out of the viewport) it shows up.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36573567/stackoverflow.jpg

It's some sort of a graphic bug due to the rotation maybe. I've tried to fix it with

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

and

```
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

but nothing worked.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle? Or link to your page?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36573567/dev/index.html
I just noticed that this bug only shows up when working locally. Lol, and It shows up often when the inspector is open. Previously I've had other bugs because of the inspector being open.

I guess I don't have a problem then :) Sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. The bug showed only when I'm working locally + an open inspector. I guess I don't have a problem after all :)